# Make cyclically dependent model properties queriable in graphene-django

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

Say I have Django models looking as follows:

```
class User(Model):
    username = CharField(...)

    @property
    def projects(self):
        return # projects the user is assigned to

class Project(Model):
    name = CharField(...)

    @property
    def users(self):
        return # users assigned to the project

class Assignment(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    project = ForeignKey(Project)
```

(I intentionally did not write the querysets for the properties to make the code more readable.)

I would like to be able to see those properties in graphene-django queries. My `ModelType` classes look like this:

```
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    projects = List(ProjectType)


class ProjectType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Project

    users = List(UserType)
```

However, this code does not work, since `ProjectType` in the `UserType` class is undefined, and swapping those classes won't help much.

I tried to not include the properties at all and after all the `ModelType` classes are created, I tried to add the properties via `setattr()`. Such hack for sure sets the attributes so the classes have the exact same structure, but it seems to be too late: the properties are not accessible from GraphQL at all.

Now I ran out of ideas. Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The attributes of a `ModelType` class matter only when the class is being initialized. A way how to add fields later is to add them directly to the place where they are. The solution:

```
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User


class ProjectType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Project

UserType._meta.fields["projects"] = get_field_as(List(ProjectType), _as=Field)
ProjectType._meta.fields["users"] = get_field_as(List(UserType), _as=Field)
```

and both properties work as desired.